# Split a string with comma while ignoring commas before and when followed with a whitespace

Tags: regex, scala, csv, split

I've been banging my head on this for a bit - but is essence what I'm looking to solve is I have a string that's being parse from larger string that contains a number of fields delimited by a comma "," looks like this:

```
{parameters format=,, =separtorChar=|, field.delim=,}
```

Note as you may notice - some of the "values" are in fact commas"," themselves - hence when I split on a "," it creates an erroneous result.

I've been able to parse out the delimiting commas with the following regex:

```
(?<![,],),(?!,)
```

Which gives me the delimiting comma however also ends up treating the comma at the end of the string as a delimiter instead of a value
result:

```
{parameters format=,{,} =separtorChar=|{,} field.delim={,}} <-- this comma "," is a value
```

There's no guarantee that the comma will always be next to the "=" so I couldn't use a pattern search or omit spaces as the value needs to stay intact as it is between the "=" and the following field or end of line

Any thought or recommendations would be greatly appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you want to match the comma that is followed by a whitespace? `(?<!,,),(?=\s)`? How can you verbally describe the pattern you need? It should not match a comma that is not immediately preceded with two commas and... ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew WOW!!  so simple I can believe I missed that - that's exactly what it was !! OMG ! where were you last night at 4 am when I was banging my head on my keyboard LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `(?=\s)` positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a whitespace:

```scala
(?<!,,),(?=\s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aYVHkO/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<!,,)` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with `,,` (two commas)
- `,` - a comma
- `(?=\s)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a whitespace.